# how to access an element's attriubute image souce using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below html element.And i want to apply the src value it has for the attribute data-val-required to another element's(id='Title2') src property.

```
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" data-val-required="<img class='validateicon'
       src='https://mysprt/Content/Images/16x16-red-alert.png'/><font color='Red'>*</font> Required" >
```

I tried the below and it works but i want to know if there is a better approach than this ?

```
javascript:alert($($('#Title').attr('data-val-required')).attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data attribute instead:

```
$($('#Title').data('val-required')).attr('src');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6TLW/)**

Comment: I get the error "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'" when i run it with your statemenet in browser.

Comment: @krrishna: have you checked the fiddle/.

Comment: It works in the fiddle/.But not sure why is not working in my page.May be some issue with my code.But i got the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** : return the value at the named data store of the selector.

.attr() can be suggested only in some specific cases - **[Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)**

```
$($('#Title').data('val-required')).attr('src');
```

Or

```
$($('#Title').data('valRequired')).attr('src');
```

> .data() automatically camelCases the '-'

Or

```
$($('#Title').data('val-required')).prop('src');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Q8r/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{    
   alert($($('#Title').data('val-required')).attr('src'));
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/260/)